# Data not appearing in file written using HADOOP LocalFileSystem

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I have written folowing code to write a couple of bytes to a local file using LocalFileSytem of HADOOP.i have used flush() , which as per my knowledge flushes JVM buffer and hsynch() flushes OS buffers leading to data being written to disk. But here in my case its data is not appearing in the file "1.txt" . But while i am closing the out put stream using close()[for the time being i have commented out in my code] data is perfectly appearing. Please rectify me if my understanding about flush() and hsynch() is correct or not ? If correct why data is not appearing ?

```
package hdfsTrying.hdfstrying;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import com.google.protobuf.ByteString.Output;

public class LocalFileAccess {
    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
        Path p = new Path("/home/priya/1.txt");
        FileSystem fs;
        Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
        try
        {
            fs= FileSystem.getLocal(cfg);

            FSDataOutputStream out = fs.create(p);
            out.write("Hi This should be written to file 1.txt".getBytes());
            out.flush();
            out.hsync();
            //out.close();
            FileStatus fst[]  = fs.listStatus(p);
            for(FileStatus g:fst)
             System.out.println(g.getPath());

        }
        catch(IOException io)
        {
            System.out.println("I am having exception");
            System.out.println(io.getMessage());
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Have you got answer for this question?

Answer (score 3):

When you use the `flush` method to write the file to disk, it will only be written to disk when it reaches a block's worth of data. Therefore, if your data is smaller (which is your case) you need to call the `hsync` function to force all buffers to be synchronized. However, this method only works for Hadoop versions over 1.x, since before that this method only made a call to `hflush`. If your Hadoop version is lower, try calling `sync` instead of `hsync`.

Comment: Hi Balduz, I have hadoop 2.2.0. What you told is correct while i am accessing hdfs , but  here i am accessing local file system(not the distributed) using LocalFileSystem of Hadoop. Its very strange is even afre my program termination , i am not able to see the data . So is it like i am loosing data .  Thanks

Comment: Yes Balduz , when i am using close it is writing data. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With LocalFileSystem, hflush and hsync won't work, flush is never called on the underlying stream. For unit testing logic that requires flush, following workaround will do the trick:

```
if (fs.getScheme().equals("file")) {
  fs.mkdirs(logPath.getParent());
  fsOutputStream = new FSDataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(logPath.toString()), null);
} else {
  fsOutputStream = fs.create(logPath);
}
```